# gsub not working while implementing in a loop

Tags: r, gsub

here i have the following dataframe `df` in R.

```
kyid    industry    amount
112     Apparel     345436
234     APPEARELS   234567
213     apparels    345678
345     Airlines    235678
123     IT          456789
124     IT          897685
```

i want to replace in industry which incorrectly written `Apparel`, or `APPEARLS` to `Apparels` .

i tried using creating a list and run it through a loop.

```
l<-c('Apparel ','APPEARELS','apparels')

for(i in range(1:3)){
    df$industry<-gsub(pattern=l[i],"Apparels",df$industry)
}
```

it is not working.only one element changes.

But, when i take the statement individually it is not creating an error and its working.

```
df$industry<-gsub(pattern=","Apparels",df$industry)
```

but this is a large dataset so i nned this to work in R please help.

Comment: Note that you can do multiple replacements in one go using a pattern that involves `|`: `gsub(pattern = 'Apparel|APPEARLS', replacement = 'Apparels')`. See also [str_replace](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) from the stringr package.

Comment: You might want to make your life a little bit easier by using `tolower` or `toupper` on you data you want to clean, as well as `trimws`
Also, using `range(1:3)` in your `for`-loop might not give the desired result (it only loops with 1, and 3 - the range of `c(1, 2, 3)`)

Comment: From my point of view you shouldn't use regular expressions here since you want to match exactly. Just use `==` with `replace` or similar stuff. Also, your variable looks like it should be a factor. Then you could work on the factor levels.

Comment: regular expressions exist to match general patterns. Running a loop to match different instances of the same word is antithetical to the use of regular expressions. `gsub("appe?arels?", "Apparels", ignore.case=TRUE)`. It is worth the time required to learn this amazing tool.

Answer (score 2):

`sub` without loop using `|` :

```
l <- c("Apparel" , "APPEARELS", "apparels")
# Using OPs data
sub(paste(l, collapse = "|"), "Apparels", df$industry)
# [1] "Apparels" "Apparels" "Apparels" "Airlines" "IT" "IT"
```

I'm using `sub` instead of `gsub` as there's only one occurrence of pattern in a string (at least in example).

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use something like `sprintf("^%s$", paste(l, collapse = "|"))` for the pattern.  This will force an exact match from the start to the end of the string. Otherwise, you might make a change to a partial string that has other character either before or after one of the patterns in `l`

Answer (score 1):

While `range` returns a sequence in Python, it returns the minimum and maximum of a vector in R:

```
range(1:3)
# [1] 1 3
```

Instead, you could use `1:3` or `seq(1,3)` or `seq_along(l)`, which all return

```
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Also note the difference between `'Apparel'` and `'Apparel '`.

So

```
df<-read.table(header=T, text="kyid    industry    amount
112     Apparel     345436
234     APPEARELS   234567
213     apparels    345678
345     Airlines    235678
123     IT          456789
124     IT          897685")
l<-c('Apparel','APPEARELS','apparels')
for(i in seq_along(l)){
  df$industry<-gsub(pattern=l[i],"Apparels",df$industry)
}
df
# kyid industry amount
# 1  112 Apparels 345436
# 2  234 Apparels 234567
# 3  213 Apparels 345678
# 4  345 Airlines 235678
# 5  123       IT 456789
# 6  124       IT 897685
```